# Filter columns from a PipelinedRDD

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have a pipelinedRDD that contains lot of key:value pairs, I need to filter out only few of them and ignore the rest. How can I achieve this?

Sample RDD Data

```
{ 
"PLAN_ID": "7de7cc2d-95be-4b7f-bb2a-77482dc03853"
,"Week": "2017 Wk 11"
,"Demand": 0.0
,"Sales": 0.0
,"LostSales": 0.0
,"InventoryBOP": 0.0
,"InventoryEOP": 2666.0
,"Receipt": 2666.0
,"RecommendedReceipt": 2666.0
,"WeeksOnHand": 0.0
,"WeeksOfSales": 0.0}
```

I want to filter only PLAN_ID, Receipt, RecommendedReceipt,InventoryEOP, InventoryBOP.

kindly let me know how this can be done,as I am unable to figure this out. 
Sorry for asking a lot :(

Comment: what is the meaning of this list of key:values? is it a sample of one line of RDD? do you have all those fields in every line of RDD?

Comment: Hi Yaron, the rdd that i am returning is of type pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD . There are some cases where all the fields are not available in every row of rdd. in such a case i want to remove those lines from RDD and process the remaining rows and make a Dataframe

Comment: please execute "rdd.take(5)" on your rdd, and share the output as part of your question

Comment: Hi Yaron, please find sample rdd data . https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxSCVyKfGOO6NFItWU14a3FGN1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I started to review the data, and it is more than 100,000 bytes long. Can you please confirm that each line has the same keys?

Comment: Yaron, Actually I fixed the issues by implementing a filter in the data before going through map.