# How to apply filters on an pySpark pipelined RDD

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I want to put filter on a pipelined RDD and extract specific columns where the value is not NULL. How can I achieve this?

Comment: please provide detailed question, what is the input, what is the expected output, what have you tried.  Also - are you referring to RDD to DataFrame?

Comment: Hi Yaron, This was my original question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969161/filter-columns-from-a-pipelinedrdd

Comment: the description of the other question isn't good enough.